# JQuery submit textarea on return key press using AJAX post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have comment boxes beneath posts on my website, and I'd like people to be able to submit a comment by simply pressing the return key. The comment is also inserted via ajax.

My code as it stands is:

**For the AJAX post and capturing the enter key:**

```
$('textarea#scat').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){

        var myClass = $(this).attr("class");  
        var comment = $("textarea." + myClass).val();  
        if (comment == "") {  
        return false;  
        }

        if (!$.trim($("textarea." + myClass).val())) {  
        return false;  
        }

        var cid = $("input.c_" + myClass).val();  
        var itemid = $("input.i_" + myClass).val();  
        var type = $("input.t_" + myClass).val();  
        var top = $("input.l_" + myClass).val();  

        var dataString = 'comment='+ comment + '&cid=' + cid + '&itemid=' + itemid + '&type=' + type;  
       //alert (dataString);return false;  
       $.ajax({  
           type: "POST",  
           url: "addcomment.php",  
           data: dataString,  
           success: function() {  
               $('#c').load('ajax/querylc.php?oid=' + myClass); 
               $("textarea." + myClass).val('');
           }  
       });  
      return false;  
  };
});
```

**And my comment box code:**

```
<div id='statuscomadd' class="<?php echo $sid; ?>" style='text-align:center; padding-top:2px; margin-left:12.5px; border-left:1px #a3a3a3 solid; border-right:1px #a3a3a3 solid; border-bottom:1px #a3a3a3 solid; height:40px; width:420px; vertical-align:middle;'>
    <img id="scati<?php echo $sid; ?>" src='<?php if ($dp == null) { echo 'img/unknown_user.jpg'; } else { echo 'pf/' . $uid . '/' . $dp; } ?>' style='height:36.5px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:6px;'>
    <form action='addcomment.php' method='post' id='ac' style='display:inline; border:0px; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0;'>
        <textarea id='scat' style='outline: none; height:30px; width:315px; font-family:Arial; border:0px; resize:none; margin-bottom:5px; border:1px solid #C9C9C9; display:inline;' name='comment' class='<?php echo $sid; ?>'></textarea>
        <input type='hidden' class="t_<?php echo $sid; ?>" name='type' value='status' />
        <input type='hidden' class="i_<?php echo $sid; ?>" name='itemid' value='<?php echo $sid; ?>'/>
        <input type='hidden' class="c_<?php echo $sid; ?>" name='cid' value='<?php echo $uid ?>' />

    </form>
</div>
```

The post works if I use a form submit button, but not if I use the return key, all that happens currently is that it adds a new line, which I only want to happen on shift+enter.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: first thing is that data in AJAX can take an object too. I prefer to use this since it works better than trying to form the string yourself. Also is it echoing $sid? If you take out the if statements for returning false what happens? Also does it get down the alert() you have commented out? Does your browser console say anything?

Comment: The AJAX runs perfectly, if I use a submit button. It's just that it isn't triggered by the keypress...

Comment: What if you access the which proerty directly as well: `if (event.which == 13) {`

Comment: Last comment taken from exmaple here: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: Maybe you can just hide the submit button and just call $('#submit_button').click(); inside the function which listens for the enter event. Then include your form submit code inside the $('#submit_button').click() function or $('#form').submit() function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'keypress' use the following.

```
$('textarea#scat').bind('**keydown**', function(e) {

if(e.keyCode==13){
```

Answer (score 0):

Form the Docs on keypress http://api.jquery.com/keypress/:

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.

So you actually want to use keydown with your function instead: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the class attribute of your textarea.

Is the PHP variable $sid a number?

If so, try adding a non-numeric prefix like

```
class='classname_<?php echo $sid; ?>'
```